# Tiling 9 images in a square in a div... Current way?

Tags: html, css, frontend, tabular

I'm trying to display 9 square images in a 3x3 grid. I'd like to be able to stretch the bounding box of the overall 3x3 square, thus stretching each of the tiles.

My solution would involve tables - I suppose that's shunned upon nowadays? What would be the right way to do this among modern and current-generation browsers?

Please be kind - the last time I did frontend dev, tables were in fashion and it wasn't quite Y2K.

Comment: I'd suggest using an <ol> with 9 <li> elements, setting the width of each to be 33%.

Comment: Possible solution: Use an <ul> with 9 <li> and give the ul these css rules: `columns: 3; -webkit-columns: 3; -moz-columns: 3;`

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of 3x3 fluid squares. That changes when the height or width are changed.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
html, body{
    width:100%; 
    width:100%; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}

#container {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}
.square{ 
    border:1px solid #000;         
    padding-bottom: 30%; 
    height: 0;
    width:30%; 
    margin:1%; 
    float:left; 
    display:block;
}
```

And a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gn9g4/1/)

---

On suggestion of **danrhul** a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gn9g4/2/)** with `<ul>`

Comment: I think this is the best solution of the three, but you should use <ul> or <ol> instead of divs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i put a second working demo based on <ul>

Comment: the padding-bottom:30% was what i was missing - not sure what that does though.. but even setting width:33% seems to mess things up, or omitting padding-bottom

Comment: i have a `margin` on all sizes of `1%`, thats why i set the `.square width on 30%`, so when you set in on `33%` its not so crazy that it messes things up..

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? Put the images inside the boxed and change the overall container size. (it will not auto fit, you will need to set the size of the container yourself) Just wanted to put this in here as I'm sure you can use it.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="boxes">Box 1</div>
        <div class="boxes">Box 2</div>
        <div class="boxes">Box 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="boxes">Box 4</div>
        <div class="boxes">Box 5</div>
        <div class="boxes">Box 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="boxes">Box 7</div>
        <div class="boxes">Box 8</div>
        <div class="boxes">Box 9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
}
.boxes {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.row {
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 33%;    
    float: left;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gLsR3/)

Comment: Well I did say, change the overall width and height. Im guessing all images will be matching width and height.

Comment: Hmm, so using a rows approach, is there a way to auto-fit without having to set container pixel size? (See solution above)

Answer (score 0):

Use `%` for dimensions and `float` for images:

```
img {
    display: block;
    float: left; 
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 33.3%; 
}
```

check: http://jsfiddle.net/xSEnd/1/